# flutter upgrade gradle from 6.7 to 8

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter mobile application running on gradle 6.7, I need to upgrade to 8, is that possible? not easy to do?

```
[   +2 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[  +55 ms] * Where:
[        ] Script 'C:\programs\Flutter\flutter_windows_3.7.12-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 482
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
[        ] > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
[        ]    > Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Closure) when the project is already evaluated.
[        ] * Try:
[        ] > Run with --debug option to get more log output.
[        ] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Exception is:
[        ] org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
```